# image.onLoad -- how should I keep data available until this triggers?

Tags: javascript

```
//Draw Icon
for (var i = 0; i < diagram.Children.length; i++) {
    if (diagram.Children[i].Icon != -1) {
        var myImage = new Image();

        myImage.xOffset = diagram.Children[i].Offset.X;
        myImage.yOffset = diagram.Children[i].Offset.Y;
        myImage.componentName = diagram.Children[i].Name;
        myImage.componentLevel = diagram.Level;
        myImage.componentID = diagram.ID;
        myImage.type = diagram.Type;

        myImage.onload = function () {
            var self = this;
            var iconImage = new Kinetic.Image({
                image: self,
                x: self.xOffset,
                y: self.yOffset,
                tooltip: CreateTooltip(self.componentName, self.componentID, self.type),
                componentLevel: self.componentLevel,
                componentID: self.componentID
            });

            _stage.diagramLayer.add(iconImage);
            _stage.diagramLayer.draw();
        }

        //TODO: IE8+ doesn't support data URI's unless they are defined in css. 
        //myImage.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + diagram.Children[i].Icon;
        myImage.src = '../PlanView/RenderIcon?IconID=' + diagram.Children[i].Icon;
    }
}
```

It seems counter-intuitive to have to store my data as properties of image before loading the image only to be able to access those properties during the 'onload' event. I was unsuccessful at finding an alternative, though. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are in scope.  The issue is that `i` (and any other variable re-assigned within the loop) will change prior to the event firing.   If you simply pull that code out into a function, the problem is solved.

```
for (var i = 0; i < diagram.Children.length; i++) {
    if (diagram.Children[i].Icon != -1) {

        doImageStuff(diagram, i);
    }
}

...

function doImageStuff(diagram, i){
        var myImage = new Image();

        var xOffset = diagram.Children[i].Offset.X;

        /* etc. */

        myImage.onload = function () {
            // do stuff and use variables such as xOffset here
        }
}
```

In this way, the `i` within your function will not change as the loop continues.

---

**EDIT:** To address the question in the comments about an anonymous function.  You could do something like this, though I find it a bit messy:

```
for (var i = 0; i < diagram.Children.length; i++) {
    if (diagram.Children[i].Icon != -1) {

        (function(diagram, i){
            var myImage = new Image();

            var xOffset = diagram.Children[i].Offset.X;

            /* etc. */

            myImage.onload = function () {
                // do stuff and use variables such as xOffset here
            }
        })(diagram, i);
    }
}
```

There are also other alternatives, which I find even messier, such as an anonymous function that returns a function.

```
myImage.onload = (function (diagram, i) {
                     return function(){
                         // do stuff here using the variables
                     }
                 })(diagram, i);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I will accept it as the answer if this is the best possible. Would it be possible to pass the parameters of doImageStuff to the anonymous function? If I try myImage.onload = function (diagram, i){} diagram and i go out of scope.

Comment: Updated my answer to address the anonymous function thing.  It can't be done exactly as you described, but is possible.  I just find it cleaner to separate it out.  The important part here is that the anonymous function needs to be invoked in order to "copy" the variables.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with your original solution -- it is indeed cleaner.